# Fastest way to filter non frequent words inside lists of words

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing, apply, text-mining

I've a dataset containing lists of tokens in csv format like this:

```
song, tokens
aaa,"['everyon', 'pict', 'becom', 'somebody', 'know']"
bbb,"['tak', 'money', 'tak', 'prid', 'tak', 'littl']"
```

First i want to find all the words that appears in text at least a certain amount of time, let's say 5, and this is easily done:

```
# converters simply reconstruct the string of tokens in a list of tokens
tokens = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv',
                      converters={'tokens': lambda x: x.strip("[]").replace("'", "").split(", ")})

# List of all words
allwords = [word for tokens in darklyrics['tokens'] for word in tokens]
allwords = pd.DataFrame(allwords, columns=['word'])

more5 = allwords[allwords.groupby("word")["word"].transform('size') >= 5]
more5 = set(more5['word'])
frequentwords = [token.strip() for token in more5]
frequentwords.sort()
```

Now i want to remove for each list of tokens those who appear inside frequentwords, to do so i'm using this code:

```
def remove_non_frequent(x):
    global frequentwords
    output = []

    for token in x:
        if token in frequentwords:
            output.append(token)

    return output

def remove_on_chunk(df):
    df['tokens'] = df.apply(lambda x: remove_non_frequent(x['tokens']), axis=1)

    return df


def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_split=10, n_cores=4):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_split)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

lyrics_reconstructed = parallelize_dataframe(lyrics, remove_on_chunk)
```

The non multiprocess version take around 2.30-3 hours to compute, while this versione takes 1 hour.

Surely it's a slow process because i've to perform the search of circa 130 milions tokens in a list of 30k elements, but i'm quite sure my code is not particularly good.

Is there a faster and surely better way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while but i'll post the correct solution to the problem, thantk sto Marek because it's just a slightly modification of his code.
He uses sets which can't handle duplicates, so the obvious idea is to reuse the same code but with multisets.
I've worked with this implementation https://pypi.org/project/multiset/

```
from collections import Counter
import re
from multiset import Multiset

rgx = re.compile(r"[\[\]\"' \n]")  # data cleanup

# load and pre-process the data
counter = Counter()
data = []
with open('tt1', 'r') as o:
    o.readline()
    for line in o:
        parts = line.split(',')

        clean_parts = [re.sub(rgx, "", i) for i in parts[1:]]
        counter.update(clean_parts)

        ms = Multiset()
        for word in clean_parts:
            ms.add(word)

        data.append([parts[0], ms])

n = 2  # <- here set threshold for number of occurences

common_words = Multiset()

# I'm using intersection with the most common words since
# common_words is way smaller than uncommon_words

# Intersection returns the lowest value count between two multisets
# E.g ('sky', 10) and ('sky', 1) will produce ('sky', 1)
# I want the number of repeated words in my document so i set the
# common words counter to be very high
for item in counter.items():
    if item[1] >= n:
        common_words.add(item[0], 100)

# process the data
clean_data = []
for s, r in data:
    clean_data.append((s, r.intersection(common_words)))

output_data = []
for s, ms in clean_data:
    tokens = []
    for item in ms.items():
        for i in range(0, item[1]):
            tokens.append(item[0])

    output_data.append([s] + [tokens])
```

This code extracts the most frequent words and filters each document according to this list, on a 110 MB dataset performs the job in less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

go for `Set` operations. I've saved your example data to "tt1" file, so this should work. Also, If you are generating the data somehow yourself, do yourself a favour and drop the quotes and square brackets. It would save you time in pre-process.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

rgx = re.compile(r"[\[\]\"' \n]")     # data cleanup

# load and pre-process the data
counter = Counter()
data = []
with open('tt1', 'r') as o:
    o.readline()
    for line in o:
        parts = line.split(',')
        clean_parts = {re.sub(rgx, "", i) for i in parts[1:]}
        counter.update(clean_parts)
        data.append((parts[0], clean_parts))


n = 2                         # <- here set threshold for number of occurences
common_words = {i[0] for i in counter.items() if i[1] > n}

# process the data
clean_data = []
for s, r in data:
    clean_data.append((s, r - common_words))
```

Comment: Insanely good, thank you very much. It takes something like 2 minutes!

Comment: There is still a small problem, i'l like to preserve repeated words that are not common (i'm using your code but with < n). 

I can't obviously do with a set, any suggestion?
Right now i've slightly modified your code to work with lists, but the required time dramatically increase.

Comment: You want also the words with occurences < n? Then do just `uncommon_words = {i[0] for i in counter.items() if i[1] <= n}`. Or something different?

Comment: in the csv i've rows like ['life', ..., 'life'] i need to keep 'life' twice because this could be meaningful when performing something like tf-idf for classification purposes.

 
The modification of your code with lists is still faster than mine (30 minutes), but is not as fast as before, i should change set with multiset, but there's no default implementation in Python.

Still +1 because is still better than my code.